# Why is my XML Design not showing in PasscodeView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, passcode

I can't find any visible errors just this error "Failed to Instantiate one or more classes". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwzvI.png)
I don't know what's causing the problem I think it's the library but I'm not sure.

I tried:
1 Rebuilding the app
2 Restarting my Android Studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It says java.lang.NullPointerException on your code at line 402.

NullPointerException is a runtime exception in Java that occurs when a variable is accessed which is not pointing to any object and refers to nothing or null. Since the NullPointerException is a runtime exception, it doesn't need to be caught and handled explicitly in application code.

So you need to handle an exception if you want the code to accept null. If it is not supposed to return null, you have to figure out why it is returning null or not pointing to any object.